# Encrypt data with using public key file in C language

Tags: c, ssl, openssl, public-key-encryption

I need to pass the data to the server2.c through another server1.c in the middle.
Before calling SSL_write() I want to encrypt my data using public key file pubkey.pem of the server2.c so the server1.c cannot understand the data and simply writes it to the server2.c

What system call I should use that takes data and public key file as arguments?

Answer (score 1):

> What system call I should use that takes data and public key file as arguments?

In the C language with OpenSSL, there are no arguments like in a program with `argc` and `argv`. There are functions and parameters.

In OpenSSL, you use the EVP functions to do it. In particular, `EVP_Seal` to encrypt and `EVP_Open` to decrypt using public key cryptography. See the [EVP(3) man pages](https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/evp.html) for more details. Or see OpenSSL's [EVP Wiki page](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP) for details.

There are `EVP_encrypt` and `EVP_Decrypt` functions, but they are used for symmetric key encryption, and not public key encryption.